# Instance & Method Hiding: The Point Is?

Tags: java, method-hiding, data-hiding

Can someone please explain the reason and benefit for instance and method hiding, in particular what advantage would I gain duplicating superclass members?  Doesn't that fly in the face of inheritance whose purpose is to further define a class and improve upon it?

Comment: Don't forget it's about the names. It doesn't have to be the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly disagree. As elements can only be hidden when they're static, it doesn't make a difference, if you're using the good practice of calling static elements by its declaring class and not by its subclasses or instances.

As the example taken from the [Java tutorials page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

```
public class Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Animal");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Animal");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The static method in Cat");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method in Cat");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal.testClassMethod();
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Will output

```
The static method in Animal
The instance method in Cat
```

As you can see, even with another static method implemented with the same name, the one declared in Animal wasn't really hidden, unless you call `Cat.testClassMethod();` and expect the same result.

It's just a question of abstracting the idea of inheritance here, because static elements aren't really inherited, just acessible to the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

In Java method hiding happens when static methods with identical signatures are defined in classes related through inheritance. It does *not* happen to instance methods, which produce an override in this situation.

Java language designers needed to assign one of two possible semantics to it - the choices were to hide or to override the static method.

I think the reason why they went with hiding is that it is much easier to understand and to implement. It also has a strong potential of improving performance, because the dispatch of static methods could be done at compile time.

Overall, this wasn't a big deal, because you have access to the hidden methods as well, as long as you specify the class name where the hidden static method is defined.

Comment: The fact that it applies to `static` methods therefore doesn't affect inheritance.